# Android, issue with mofified ListView

Tags: android, list

I created a modified ListView, in order to display various information on the screen. Now I want to perform an individual action on the View the user has clicked, like making it invisible.

I tried something, but it doesn't seem to work properly. It makes each of the 4 views invisible, instead of just 1. Can somebody can help me, please?

```
public class affichageListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   public void actionC(){
     ListListView.get(0).test();
   } 
   // some more code ...
}
public class affichageListView extends LinearLayout {
   // some more code ...
   public void test(){
     textViewTest.setVisibility(GONE);
   } 
}
```

EDIT: I forgot a part of my code

```
    public class listeVideo extends ListFragment{
   private affichageListViewAdapter adapter;
   @Override
      public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

   adapter.test();

}
}
```

Edit 2: How i Use your method

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        affichageListeVue = new affichageListView(mContext);
    } 
    else {
        affichageListeVue = (affichageListView) convertView;
    }
    affichageListeVue.ajouter(getItem(position));
    affichageListeVue.getSize(size);

    affichageListeVue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);//I use this method just for if the click works
        }
    });

    return affichageListeVue;
}
```

EDIT 3:

```
public class affichageListView extends LinearLayout {
private TextView mTextView;

public affichageListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public affichageListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public affichageListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    inflate(getContext(), R.layout.affichafe_list_view, this);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitre);
}
```

}

Comment: Post your `affichageListeView` constructor please. And also, in your original question it is named `affichageListeView` and in your Edit 2 it is named `affichageListeVue`. Are those supposed to be references to the same object?

Comment: here it is, affichageListeVue is the name of the object and affichageListeView is the class name

Comment: I think the problem is caused by convertView.

Answer (score 0):

So, what you need is to set up OnClickListener(View v) method for your layout which populates ListView item.
If you're inflating an item using XML resource, add this attribute to your XML item layout:

```
android:onClick="MyMethod"
```

Then inside your MainActivity declare `MyMethod(View v)` as following:

```
public void MyMethod(View v) {
    TextView textViewTest = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lookupId);
    textViewTest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Note: Change the `R.id.lookupId` with the id of the text view item within your layout that you want to hide. I understand this is pretty short explanation, ask in the comments whatever you want. Cheers :)

EDIT: I forgot, if you're building your ListView dynamically, you need to set the OnItemClickListener within your `getView(...)` method and return that same view. For example:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View ConvertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View tempView = ConvertView;
    if(tempView == null) {
        //Add all the values and items that you want to the tempView
        //You are checking if the tempView is null to recycle old ListView items
    }
    tempView.setOnClickListner(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Implement here a method to be fired when user clicks an item
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks bu it seems i have the same problem with your code, It makes each of the 4 views invisible, instead of just 1.

Comment: Could you edit your post with how you implemented my method? You're not supposed to add onListItemClick() but onClickListener() to the view which populates the item of the ListView's adapter.

Comment: Here it is, see my post above